# Export "lulcc package" output map to GeoTIFF file using R

Tags: r, export, mapping, modeling, geotiff

I am a student and just learning R. I am interested in trying the "lulcc package" by Simon Moulds for land-use modeling.
I got the modeling output map for t19 and t20, but I only want to export t20 as GeoTIFF so that it can be opened in ArcGIS. How can I solve it? Hopefully, anyone can help and thank you in advance.

this is the output map from plot(clues.model) 
[lulcc map output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5Y2A.png)
Here is the code running in R:

```
library(lulcc)

## see lulcc-package examples

## Not run: 

## Plum Island Ecosystems

## load data
data(pie)

## observed maps
obs <- ObsLulcRasterStack(x=pie,
                          pattern="lu", 
                          categories=c(1,2,3), 
                          labels=c("Forest","Built","Other"), 
                          t=c(0,6,14))
obs

plot(obs)

crossTabulate(obs, times=c(0,14))

## explanatory variables
ef <- ExpVarRasterList(x=pie, pattern="ef")
ef

part <- partition(x=obs[[1]], size=0.1, spatial=TRUE)
train.data <- getPredictiveModelInputData(obs=obs, ef=ef, cells=part[["train"]])

forms <- list(Built ~ ef_001+ef_002+ef_003,
              Forest ~ ef_001+ef_002,
              Other ~ ef_001+ef_002)

glm.models <- glmModels(formula=forms, family=binomial, data=train.data, obs=obs)

## test ability of models to predict allocation of forest, built and other
## land uses in testing partition
test.data <- getPredictiveModelInputData(obs=obs, ef=ef, cells=part[["test"]])

glm.pred <- PredictionList(models=glm.models, newdata=test.data)
glm.perf <- PerformanceList(pred=glm.pred, measure="rch")

plot(list(glm=glm.perf, rpart=rpart.perf, rf=rf.perf))

## test ability of models to predict location of urban gain 1985 to 1991
part <- rasterToPoints(obs[[1]], fun=function(x) x != 2, spatial=TRUE)
test.data <- getPredictiveModelInputData(obs=obs, ef=ef, cells=part, t=6)

glm.pred <- PredictionList(models=glm.models[[2]], newdata=test.data)
glm.perf <- PerformanceList(pred=glm.pred, measure="rch")

plot(list(glm=glm.perf))

## obtain demand scenario
dmd <- approxExtrapDemand(obs=obs, tout=19:20)
matplot(dmd, type="l", ylab="Demand (no. of cells)", xlab="Time point",
        lty=1, col=c("Green","Red","Blue"))
legend("topleft", legend=obs@labels, col=c("Green","Red","Blue"), lty=1)

## get neighbourhood values
w <- matrix(data=1, nrow=3, ncol=3)
nb <- NeighbRasterStack(x=obs[[1]], weights=w, categories=2)

## create CLUE-S model object
clues.rules <- matrix(data=1, nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE) 

clues.parms <- list(jitter.f=0.0002,
                    scale.f=0.000001,
                    max.iter=1000,
                    max.diff=50, 
                    ave.diff=50) 

clues.model <- CluesModel(obs=obs,
                          ef=ef,
                          models=glm.models,
                          time=19:20,
                          demand=dmd,
                          elas=c(0.2,0.2,0.2),
                          rules=clues.rules,
                          params=clues.parms)

## perform allocation
clues.model <- allocate(clues.model)

plot(clues.model)
```

Comment: Which object/output you want to export as .tif file?

Comment: Output map from plot(clues.model). There are two contiguous maps (t19 and t20), I want to export only t20 as GeoTIFF.

Comment: What does t19 and t20 mean?

Comment: t19 and t20 means land-use prediction results in the 19th and 20th year after observed data

Answer (score 0):

You can use `raster` package for exporting the output as .tif file like

```
library(raster)
writeRaster(output, "Filename.tif", format = "GTiff",
            datatype = "FLT4S", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try your suggestion